# Reading and displaying json data using Polymer

Tags: json, html, polymer, polymer-2.x

I am new to polymer and I am trying to read JSON data in a custom-element and display it in other element.

This is my JSON data:

**`jsonData.json`**

```
[
  {
    "name":"Ladies+Chrome+T-Shirt",
    "title":"Ladies Chrome T-Shirt"
  },
  {
    "name":"Ladies+Google+New+York+T-Shirt",
    "title":"Ladies Google New York T-Shirt"
  }
]
```

This is my `shop-app.html` file where I try to read data from JSON file (I am not sure if this is correct or not as I am not able to test it):

```
<dom-module id="shop-category-data">
  <script>
    (function(){
      class ShopCategoryData extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() { return 'shop-category-data'; }
        static get properties() { return {
          data: {
              type: Object,
              computed: '_computeData()',
              notify: true
          }
        }}
        _computeData() {
            this._getResource( {
                url: 'data/jsonData.json',
                onLoad(e){
                    this.set('data.items', JSON.parse(e.target.responseText));
                }
            })
        }
        _getResource(rq) {
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.addEventListener('load', rq.onLoad.bind(this));
            xhr.open('GET', rq.url);xhr.send();
          }
        }
      customElements.define(ShopCategoryData.is, ShopCategoryData);
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

This is the element where I want to display the data I read from the JSON file:

```
<dom-module id="shop-app">
  <template>
    <app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
    <app-route
        route="{{route}}"
        pattern="/:page"
        data="{{routeData}}"
        tail="{{subroute}}">
    </app-route>
    <shop-category-data data="{{data}}"></shop-category-data>
    <template>
      <div> Employee list: </div>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
          <div>First name: <span>{{item.name}}</span></div>
          <div>Last name: <span>{{item.title}}</span></div>
    </template>
  </template>
  </template>
  <script>
    class ShopApp extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'shop-app'; }
    }
    customElements.define(ShopApp.is, ShopApp);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

The line `<shop-category-data data="{{data}}"></shop-category-data>` should give me the data, which I then try to display using dom-repeat. But nothing is being displayed. So, I think there is some mistake in my reading the JSON data.

**Edit**:
The JSON is read correctly, it is just not getting reflected back in my:

```
<shop-category-data data="{{data}}"></shop-category-data>
```

Comment: Do you get the JSON data in the first place?

Comment: Have you parsed the JSON data with JSON.stringify?

Comment: Have you tried using ready: function() {} to get the JSON instead of computer()?

Comment: @RickardElimää Please check my edit. The json is getting parsed correctly, I checked it by displaying it using console.log. It is just not getting reflected back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computed properties is not returning a value. If you want to define `data` as a computed property you must return a value from the computed property function `_computeData()`. But in your case you are using asynchronous `XMLHttpRequest`. So, if you return a value after calling `this._getResource...` you need to make it synchronous (**which no one recommends**).

Plnkr for *synchronous* method: http://plnkr.co/edit/jdSRMR?p=preview

Another way is calling the method inside `ready()`. This is asynchronous.

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/pj4dgl?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

It's not getting reflected back because the json is assigned to `data.items`, rather than to `data` itself.

```
this.set('data', JSON.parse(e.target.responseText));
```

It's recommended to use `<iron-ajax>`, and scrap `<shop-category-data>`. e.g. replace the following line

```
<shop-category-data data="{{data}}"></shop-category-data>
```

with

```
<iron-ajax auto url="data/jsonData.json" handle-as="json"
    last-response="{{data}}"></iron-ajax>
```